# Local Storage issues in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, render

I'm trying to use Local Storage in one of my Vue component and I need to be able to render depend on allready exist there and toggle some data in Local Storage on button click. Also there should be changes on UI depending on what was changed there. So here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div>
      <img :src="image" alt="character-image"/>
    </div>

    <div class="cardInfo">
      <p class="cardTitle">{{ name }}</p>

      <span>{{ species }}</span> - <span>{{ status }}</span>

      <Button
          :buttonText="buttonText"
          class="addToFavouritesBtn"
          @click="toggleFavourites"
      >
      </Button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { defineProps, computed } from "vue";
  import Button from '../components/Button.vue';
  import useLocalStorage from '../utils/useLocalStorage';

  const props = defineProps<{
    characterData: {
      id: string,
      name: string,
      image: string,
      species: string,
      status: string
    }
  }>();

  const { id, name, image, species, status } = props.characterData;
  const favourites = useLocalStorage([], 'favouriteCharacters');

  const buttonText = computed(() => {
    return favourites.value.some(character => character.id === id) ? 'Remove from Favourites' : 'Add to Favourites';
  });

  const toggleFavourites = () => {
    const index = favourites.value.findIndex((character) => character.id === id);

    if (index === -1) {
      console.log(1)
      // Not in favourites, add it
      favourites.value.push(props.characterData);
    } else {
      console.log(2)
      // Already in favourites, remove it
      favourites.value.splice(index, 1); // This will remove the item at the found index
    }
  };
</script>
```

I'm also using composable function in order to be able to reuse access to Local Storage through entire app

```
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export default function useLocalStorage(initialValue, key) {
    const storedValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    const val = ref(storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : initialValue);

    watch(val, (newValue) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
    }, { deep: true });

    return val;
}
```

But the problem is that when I'm clicking on Add to Favourite button it's just replace existing object in Local Storage, delete functionality is also not working. Metter in fact we never run into else statement where console.log(2) is placed even if this element is allready exist in Local Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why yet but I have fixed my problem by moving all my logic related to Local storage to the parent component.

```
<template>
  <div class="filterBar">
    <div class="container">
      <ButtonGroup :groupCategories="categoriesData"/>
      {{ activeButtonName.activeButton }}

      <!--      <div v-if="isLoading" class="spinner">Loading...</div>-->

        <button @click="prevPage">Previous</button>
        <button @click="nextPage">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div
        class="cardWrapper"
    >
      <CharacterCard
          v-for="character in characters"
          :key="character.id"
          :characterData="character"
          :favorite="favourites"
          :handleClick="toggleFavourites"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref} from "vue";
  import {watch} from "vue";
  import ButtonGroup from "../components/ButtonGroup.vue";
  import CharacterCard from '../components/CharacterCard.vue';
  import {useButtonGroup} from "@/stores/buttonGroup";
  import {usePagination} from "@/utils/usePagination";
  import useLocalStorage from '../utils/useLocalStorage';

  const categoriesData = ["All", "Human", "Animal", "Alien"];
  const activeButtonName = useButtonGroup();
  const url = ref("");

  const favourites = useLocalStorage([], 'favouriteCharacters');

  const toggleFavourites = (id, data) => {
    let dataCopy = [...favourites.value];
    const index = dataCopy.findIndex((character) => character.id === id);

    if (index === -1) {
      dataCopy.push(data);
    } else {
      dataCopy = dataCopy.filter(character => character.id !== id);
    }

    favourites.value = dataCopy;
  };

  watch(activeButtonName, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    url.value = newValue.getActiveButton.toLowerCase() === 'all'
        ? 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'
        : `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?species=${newValue.getActiveButton.toLowerCase()}`;
  });

  const {data: characters, isLoading, info, nextPage, prevPage} = usePagination(url);
</script>
```